# How to use nagios to monitor Zookeeper nodes

Tags: monitoring, nagios, zookeeper

Sorry this may be a basic question, but I am new to both nagios, and zookeeper.

My company has an application that uses zookeeper to track job status, by creating/destroying nodes. I need to be able to monitor that the number of nodes is always 2*number of wokers or less, is there a plugin that can do this already for nagios? If so which one and how would I configure it for that?

Thank you,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some ZooKeeper checks on Nagios Exchange and Monitoring Exchange.

I don't see anything that mentions checking for a specific number of nodes, but you could use one of these as a starting point. (This will probably require hacking some perl or python.)

1. https://github.com/andreisavu/zookeeper-monitoring
2. http://exchange.nagios.org/index.php?option=com_mtree&task=search&Itemid=74&searchword=zookeeper

The first link indicates that [there are monitoring scripts included with ZooKeeper](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/zookeeper/trunk/src/contrib/monitoring/check_zookeeper.py), in the contrib directory.

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple ZooKeeper Nagios checks at the link below (which you should also be able to find from the nagios exchange link in the other answer). My checks include arbitrary znode contents that you should find useful to check your application specific information.

https://github.com/harisekhon/nagios-plugins

UPDATE: I noticed yesterday that someone voted my answer down even though this is the best collection of ZooKeeper Nagios monitoring code I'm aware of in the world  (I used to work for Cloudera btw), so this evening I took half an hour to make check_zookeeper_child_znodes.pl which should solve your use case even more precisely. Enjoy.

Regards,

Hari Sekhon

https://www.linkedin.com/in/harisekhon

Comment: Both of your posts include self-promotion. If the first one was kind of okay, the second one does point in the direction of excessive spamming. I haven't flagged this one as spam, though, and just downvoted it. If you continue to advertise your plugins on SF, I'll have to spam-flag them. Please consider a) adding a link to your GitHub in your profile, b) posting more diverse and constructive answers without self-promotion.

Comment: @DeerHunter The code I gave the link for directly answers the question of ZooKeeper Nagios monitoring and is also referenced in the nagios exchange link provided in the other answer in this post that is +1. The fact I wrote it doesn't invalidate the answer or make it spam. Check it out.